# Wifi is not workig on Lenovo G710. Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: wireless, lenovo

today is my first day, using Linux and i have installed Ubuntu 17.10 but now I'm not able to use Wifi. my laptop is Lenovo G710.
I have tried almost all solutions I have seen on Internet, but no one could solve this issue..

I'm grateful to anyone could help to solve this issue. :)

Comment: Welcome! The first step is to identify your wireless device. Please open a terminal Ctrl+Alt+t  and run this command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Next, edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Dear Chili, thank you for your reply. i have reinstalled the Ubuntu again and the issue got solved :)